# How to print character code in UTF-8 (ie ASCII codes)

Tags: unicode, characters, utf-8

With

```
(let ((c (char-after (point))))
```

I get the code of the current character, and if I just do

```
(message "%X" c)
```

it prints the hexadecimal UTF-16 apparently. Is there a simple way to get UTF-8 instead?

So instead of [`9552`](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=9552) I would like to get `E9 95 92`, for example.

**Addition**: there is Alt-X `describe-char`, which prints the info, some way down the page, but I'd like a simpler way to just get the UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the exact same way that `describe-char` does it. Use `C-h f` to view the help for `describe-char`, then click the link to the source code. By reading the source code of this function and ignoring all of the complicated bits, you will find the part that converts the character into a string of bytes, and then those bytes into a longer string with a human–readable representation of them:

```lisp
(encoded-string-description (encode-coding-string (char-to-string ?…)
                                                  'utf-8)
                            nil)
```

This converts the character into a string, calls `encode-coding-string` on it to turn from a string containing a single character into a string containing the individual bytes as used by the utf-8 coding system, then calls `encoded-string-description` to create the final representation: `"#xE2 #x80 #xA6"`.

Obviously where I have used a character literal, you would use `(char-after (point))` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at `descr-text.el`, but there are other things I'd like to do in my life also, before I die.

Comment: Fair enough, but it probably wouldn’t take quite that long :)